# TravaOpenJDK11 - HotSwapAgent - DCEVM installation not found

Tags: java, intellij-idea, dcevm, hotswapagent

I'm trying to use the HotSwapAgent plugin in IntelliJ. So, I have set as "agent path" the path of `hotswap-agent.jar` (found in the Trava Open JDK folder) that I downloaded from [here](https://github.com/TravaOpenJDK/trava-jdk-11-dcevm/releases/download/dcevm-11.0.15%2B1/Openjdk11u-dcevm-windows-x64.zip). But as you can see [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xDYNz.png), I get the following error:

> DCEVM installation not found for JDK specified for the current project. You should download and install it.

However, the download link redirects [here](https://github.com/dcevm/dcevm/releases), where there are installers only up to version 8 (which seems reasonable to me since the Trava Open JDK 11 I'm trying to use is already patched and includes its own agent.

So, what am I missing here?

Comment: What IDE version do you use?

Comment: @CrazyCoder thank you very much for the answer. I am using version 2022.3.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Well, the version you mention does not require the use of the HotSwapAgent plugin or of any other plugin.

What you have to do is define the folder `dcevm-11.0.15+1` as JDK and put the following argument in the VM options of your project's debug configuration, in IntelliJ:

```
-XX:HotswapAgent=fatjar
```

or

```
-XX:HotswapAgent=core
```

In fatjar mode all plugins will be available. In core mode only core JVM plugins will be available.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer. I used the vm option and it worked! But now I get this error: HOTSWAP AGENT: 22:28:08.750 ERROR (org.hotswap.agent.annotation.handler.PluginClassFileTransformer) - InvocationTargetException in transform method on plugin 'class org.hotswap.agent.plugin.log4j2.Log4j2Plugin' class 'org/apache/logging/log4j/core/LoggerContext'.

Comment: It's hard to guess why HotSwap Agent doesn't like your Log4j plugin (CVE-2021-44228 has entered the chat) without having access to your project and configuration. It is, however, easy to disable it using the following argument: `-XX:HotswapAgent=external -javaagent:"<dcevm-path>\lib\hotswap\hotswap-agent.jar=disablePlugin=Log4j2"`.

Comment: Haha thank you once again. It worked!!!